# sql correct but in php it skips the first result

Tags: php, sql, arrays, foreach

I use this: `foreach ($result as $row) { $row["testID"], $row["subject"], ... };` to output all the values. 

The sql works fine but when I go to the page it always shows me all the output without the first element that is in the array.

For example if I have 5 tests to show to the user it only shows test 2, 3, 4 and 5 but not the first one in the array `$result.`

This is all the code (sorry it's in dutch):

```
require_once( "common.inc.php" );
    require_once( "DataObject.class.php" );

    class StatistiekAanpassen extends DataObject {
        public function toetsen() {
            $conn = parent::connect();

            $order = isset( $_GET["order"] ) ? preg_replace( "/[^ a-zA-Z]/", "", $_GET["order"] ) : "toetsID";

            /*SQL om alle toetsen op te halen*/
            $sql = "SELECT toetsID, onderwerp, puntentotaal, vak 
                    FROM Toets 
                    WHERE NOT EXISTS 
                        (SELECT * 
                        FROM LeerlingToets 
                        WHERE Toets.toetsID = LeerlingToets.toetsID AND 
                        LeerlingToets.gebruikerID = " . $_SESSION["member"]->getValue( "gebruikerID" ) . " ) order by " . $order;

            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->fetchColumn()) {
                echo "<table id=\"toetsTable\">";
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <th id="toetsTableIDth"><?php if ( $order != "toetsID" ) { ?><a href="statistiekenAanpassen.php?order=toetsID"><?php } ?>Nr<?php if ( $order != "toetsID" ) { ?></a><?php } ?></th>
                    <th id="toetsTableIDth"><?php if ( $order != "onderwerp" ) { ?><a href="statistiekenAanpassen.php?order=onderwerp"><?php } ?>Onderwerp<?php if ( $order != "onderwerp" ) { ?></a><?php } ?></th>
                    <th id="toetsTableIDth"><?php if ( $order != "vak" ) { ?><a href="statistiekenAanpassen.php?order=vak"><?php } ?>Vak<?php if ( $order != "vak" ) { ?></a><?php } ?></th>
                    <th id="toetsTableIDth"><?php if ( $order != "puntentotaal" ) { ?><a href="statistiekenAanpassen.php?order=puntentotaal"><?php } ?>Puntentotaal<?php if ( $order != "puntentotaal" ) { ?></a><?php } ?></th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    foreach ($result as $row) {
                        echo "<tr><td class=\"IDtd\"><a href=\"statistiekenAanpassen.php?toetsID=" . $row["toetsID"] . "\">" . $row["toetsID"] . "</a></td>
                    <td><a href=\"statistiekenAanpassen.php?toetsID=" . $row["toetsID"] . "\">" . $row["onderwerp"] . "</a></td>
                    <td><a href=\"statistiekenAanpassen.php?toetsID=" . $row["toetsID"] . "\">" . $row["vak"]. "</a></td>
                    <td><a href=\"statistiekenAanpassen.php?toetsID=" . $row["toetsID"] . "\">" . $row["puntentotaal"]. "</a></td></tr>";
                    }
                echo "</table>";
            } else {
                echo "<p>Er zijn nog geen toetsen.<p>";
                echo "<p>OF<p>";
                echo "<p>U heeft voor alle toetsen al punten ingegeven.<p>";
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I output all the elements, also the first one?

Comment: Most likely `$result->fetchColumn()`already fetches the first record and makes it "unavailable" for your foreach loop.

Comment: Did you check if five results are come ?

Comment: @VigneshBala, yes I've checked it. I pasted the code in phpmyadmin and changed the session var to 1 for example and it worked.

Comment: @VolkerK How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fetchcolumn makes the first column unavailable, Please use

```
$result->fetch_assoc()
```

Comment: fetch_assoc() doesn't work for me but I don't know why

Comment: then try using $results->fetch_object(); But to display this you need to refer to your columns with $row->toetsID;

Comment: Where would I need to refer and how. Sorry I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: its mysqli method for displaying results as objects, you will just use $results->fetch_object(); then in the foreach statement, you will use $row->toetsID; to display values instead of $row[toetsID];

Answer (score 3):

Most likely $result->fetchColumn()already fetches the first record and makes it "unavailable" for your foreach loop.
You can either use a flag variable to "check" whether this iteration is the first and if so print the table header. And after the loop check via this flag whether at least one record has been printed and if not print the error message.

Or you switch from a for(each) loop to a do-while loop and let the loop body print the contents of the "previous" record, i.e. the record that has already been fetched "within" the if-condition or "within" the while-condition of the previous iteration.

```
if ( !($row=$result->fetchRow()) ) { // or whatever the method to fetch one record is called
    echo "
        <p>Er zijn nog geen toetsen.<p>
        <p>OF<p>
        <p>U heeft voor alle toetsen al punten ingegeven.<p>
    ";
}
else {
    // <-- put table tag and table header here -->

    do {
        // <-- print the current table row here -->
    }
    while(  $row=$result->fetchRow() ); // again: or whatever the method to fetch one record is called

    // <-- close the table tag here  -->
}
```

(And there might be a rewind/reset method that sets the record pointer back to before the start so that foreach will iterate over the first record again.)